# Незавершенная транзакция, rollback, потеря связи

Tags: c#, oracle, транзакции

Каким образом действовать при потере связи во время отката неудачно завершенной транзакции? Понятно, что появятся нарушения целостности базы данных. Как с такими ситуациями бороться?
Связка работает через ORACLE + C#
На сайте msdn пишут, что необходимо отлавливать исключения при откате транзакции, т.к. могут произойти ошибки (например, разрыв связи). И действительно могут

Comment: А каким образом это повлияет на БД ? Транзакция все равно откатится целиком, как будто никаких изменений не вносилось вообще

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду, когда вы вызываете rollback, то в это время происходит разрыв связи?

Comment: Да, но транзакция организуется со стороны клиента и даже если произошла потеря связи гарантируется ли завершение отката?

Comment: @AleksandrNecheukhin A client process terminates abnormally, causing the transaction to be implicitly rolled back using metadata stored in the transaction table and the undo segment. из [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/transact.htm#CNCPT038)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/transact.htm#CNCPT038)

> End of a Transaction
>     A transaction ends when any of the following
>   actions occurs:
>
> ...
>
> A client process **terminates abnormally**, causing the transaction to be
>   implicitly rolled back using metadata stored in the transaction table
>   and the undo segment.

Т.е. технически проблем с целостностью быть не должно при обрыве связи